# Adjusting glossary spaces

Tags: lists, glossaries

after creating a list of mathematical parameters, I have two questions:

- Some of their respective definitions are too long, and as a consequence, they will occupy two lines. As you can see from the picture, the second line of these long definitions (e.g. Mjp), start under the mathematical symbol. This does not look good and therefore, I would like to put the second line of the definition under the first line.
- The last parameters of the list (i.e. parameter BFC, BTC, etc.) are binary parameters and therefore I would like to call them as follows: BFC\in{0,1}. However, if I write this, Latex will get an error. Is there a way I can fix it?

I leave you here the code I used:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}


\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\mathgl}[2]{
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=2cm]
      \item[\gls{#1}]#2
    \end{description}
}

\subsubsection{Parameters}
The following product flow related parameters are used:\\
\mathgl{D_j_p_y}{Demand of customer $j$ for specific product code $p$ in year $y$.}
\mathgl{Q_i}{Available capacity on facility $i$ [M cans].}
\mathgl{V_i}{Minimum volume required on facility $i$ [M cans].}
\mathgl{Fc_i}{Fixed cost of each facility $i$ [\euro].}
\mathgl{M_j_p}{Minimum volume required per product code $p$ from facility $i$ to customer $j$ [M cans].}
\mathgl{G_o_p}{Minimum volume required per product code $p$ from facility $i$ to OpCo $o$ [M cans].}
\mathgl{Fc_i}{Fixed cost of each facility $i$ [\euro].}
\mathgl{Ec__i_j_p_y}{Ex-works costs per product code p from facility i to customer j in year y [\euro/M cans]. }
\mathgl{Tc_i_j_p}{Unit transportation costs for specific product code p from facility i to customer j [\euro/M cans].}
\mathgl{Lc}{Transportation fixed costs [\euro].}
\mathgl{Vc}{Transportation variable costs [\euro].}
\mathgl{Wc_i_j_p}{Unit warehousing costs for specific product code $p$ from facility $i$ to customer $j$ [\euro/M cans].}
\mathgl{K_i_j}{Distance between facility $i$ and customer $j$ [km].}
\mathgl{Tq_i_p}{Truck capacity of supplier facility $i$ for product code $p$ [M cans].}
\mathgl{Z_i_j_p}{\ce{CO2} emissions for specific product code $p$ from facility $i$ to customer $j$ [kg \ce{CO2}/M cans].}
\mathgl{Zc}{\ce{CO2} costs [\euro/kg \ce{CO2}]. }
\mathgl{BFC}{Binary to indicate whether to include facility fixed costs or not.}
\mathgl{BTC}{Binary to indicate whether to include transportation costs or not.}
\mathgl{BEC}{Binary to indicate whether to include ex-works costs or not.}
\mathgl{BZC}{Binary to indicate whether to include CO2 emissions costs or not.}
\mathgl{BWC}{Binary to indicate whether to include warehouse costs or not.}
```

[image: results of my latex]

Comment: You should look for "flush left glossary description" or "formatting glossaries" or "align description environment text"

Comment: @Iborra I looked for it, but I could not find anything with the \newcommand you created. I suppose I need to make changes in that commands, right? But how would you do it?

Comment: You could have found the solution here: https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf after google "description environment latex manual", in page 12 --> Description styles. I'm also new in LaTeX, and I didn't know the solution. You need to make more exhaustive searches. @Max Lomba Vrouenraets

Answer (score 0):

```
\newcommand{\mathgl}[2]{
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}
    \begin{description}[style=multiline, labelwidth=1cm]
        \item[\gls{#1}]#2
    \end{description}
}
```

I think this fix your problem, and after 3 questions you have what you finally desired.

Comment: Hi @Iborra. I finally solved the problem with a really easy tabular solution.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem easily by using a tabular or a longtable (longtable in case the list occupies more than one page). If the table exceeds the margin of your text, you can play with the 9cm and adjust the width of the table (see code).

```
\subsubsection{Parameters}
The following product flow related parameters are used:\\

    \begin{longtable}{lp{9cm}}
    $D_j_p_y$ & Demand of customer $j$ for specific product code $p$ in year $y$ [M cans]. \\
    $Q_i$ & Available capacity on facility $i$ [M cans].\\
    $V_i$ & Minimum volume required on facility $i$ [M cans].\\

\end{longtable}
```